# BASH : Sum size of same name directories

Tags: linux, bash, csv, sum, du

First of all, I am a bash noob, so please be gentle :)

I am trying to sum the size of folders that are in different places but have the same name. It looks like this :

```
root
--- directory 1

------ folder 1
--------subfolder 1
--------subfolder 2
------ folder 2
--------subfolder 3
--------subfolder 4
------ folder 3
--------subfolder 5
--------subfolder 6

--- directory 2

------ folder 1
--------subfolder 1
--------subfolder 2
------ folder 2
--------subfolder 3
--------subfolder 4
------ folder 3
--------subfolder 5
--------subfolder 6
```

I am trying to sum the size of subdirectories 1 to 6 and output that to a .csv

At the moment I am simply outputting sizes of subdirectories in two seperate CSV files. One for directory 1 and one for directory 2

At the moment I have this to output sizes of subfodlers that I run where I need them :

```
du -h --max-depth=1 --block-size=GB * | grep "[\/]" | sort -n -r > ~/lists/disks/RC_job.csv
```

The output look like this :

```
40GB folder1/subfolder1

15GB folder1/subfolder2

10GB folder2/subfolder 3
...
```

I have one output for directory 1 and one for directory 2. I would like to sum the size of subfolders from directory one and two and have an output that looks like this

```
60GB subfolder1

25GB subfolder2

10GB subfolder3
```

Where subfolder1 is directory1/folder1/subfolder1 + directory2/folder1/subfolder1

This is my first post here I do not know if this enough info. I would be pleased to provide more if necessary. I am pretty sure this can be done with awl, but I haven't really used that yet.

Cheers !

Edit to answer question in comments :

(Part of the) output of `du -h /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film --max-depth=1 --block-size=GB *` is :

```
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film/nr106/nr106_0010
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film/nr106/nr106_0020
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film/nr106/nr106_0030
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film/nr106/nr106_0035
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film/nr106/nr106_0040
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film/nr106/nr106_0045
2GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film/nr106/nr106_0050
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/vault/image/film/nr106/nr106_0060
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film/nr106/nr106_0010
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film/nr106/nr106_0020
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film/nr106/nr106_0030
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film/nr106/nr106_0035
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film/nr106/nr106_0040
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film/nr106/nr106_0045
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film/nr106/nr106_0050
1GB /net/rcq-rp/job/rcq/film/nr106/nr106_0060
```

Ideally the final output would be :

```
2GB nr106_0010

etc...
```

Comment: Select your text and use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit input box to apply 'Code Sample' Formatting as needed. Please edit your question to include examples of what the 'duplicates in 2nd column' will look like, and your required output for that. Unclear if you want to 'add the size of duplicates and output results'. An ilustration with actual input and required output (as you have started to do!) will make it much easier for people to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It is done, hope it is better ! :)

Comment: Why is it necessary to have `grep "[\/]"`?

Comment: it is necessary or else the output lists directories at the same level as folder1 when I only want subdirectories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is with an associative array. An associative array maps a series of keys to values, for example:

```
directory1 -> 10 GB
directory2 -> 12 MB
directory3 -> 40 KB
```

The keys in an associative array must be unique. That's great! The paths to our directories are also unique. Let's put them in an associative array. I will show how to do this in `awk` but plenty of other languages have associative arrays (like Perl, which calls them hashes).

```
du | awk '{ val = $1; dir = $2; sizes[dir] = val }'
```

(I took out the arguments you pass to `du` for simplicity)

What does this do? `awk` reads the output of `du` line by line; for each line, it adds an element to the associative array `sizes` with the directory name as the index and the size as the value. If our original input looked like this

```
40GB folder1/subfolder1
15GB folder1/subfolder2
10GB folder2/subfolder1
```

our array would look like this:

```
sizes[folder1/subfolder1] -> 40GB
sizes[folder1/subfolder2] -> 15GB
sizes[folder2/subfolder1] -> 10GB
```

But in our final output we just want to see values for the subdirectories. `awk` has functions for string manipulation, so let's tweak our code to strip off leading directories:

```
du | awk '{ val = $1; dir = $2; sub(/^.*\//, "", dir); sizes[dir] = val }'
```

The `sub` function strips off everything from the last `/` to the beginning of the path. Now our array looks like this:

```
sizes[subfolder2] -> 15GB
sizes[subfolder1] -> 10GB
```

Great! Now we only have values for the subdirectories. There's just one little problem. The values aren't totals. Since we had more than one subdirectory named `subfolder1`, we overwrote the first value (40GB) with the second one (10GB). When we run into an index that already exists in our array, what we really want to do is add its value to the existing value:

```
du | awk '{ val = $1; dir = $2; sub(/^.*\//, "", dir); sizes[dir] += val }'
```

(I changed `sizes[dir] = val`, which uses assignment, to `sizes[dir] += val`, which adds `val` to whatever is already in `sizes[dir]`)

`awk` magically takes care of some things for us, like converting 15GB to the number 15. Now our array looks like this:

```
sizes[subfolder2] -> 15
sizes[subfolder1] -> 50
```

which shows us the totals we're looking for. Now, how do we display this? We can loop through the array and print out the keys and values like this:

```
du | awk '{ val = $1; dir = $2; sub(/^.*\//, "", dir); sizes[dir] += val } \
          END { for (dir in sizes) print dir, sizes[dir], "GB" }'
```

and our results are

```
subfolder1 50 GB
subfolder2 15 GB
```

---

**EDIT:** Here are the results I get using the `du` output in the updated question.

```
nr106_0060 2 GB
nr106_0050 3 GB
nr106_0045 2 GB
nr106_0040 2 GB
nr106_0035 2 GB
nr106_0030 2 GB
nr106_0020 2 GB
nr106_0010 2 GB
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution and a great explanation.

Just one more thing: subfolder one is not in folder1 and folder2 it is  in directory1/folder1 and directory2/folder1.

I have to du twice to find the size of folders I want to sum. Once in directory1 and another time in directory2. If I understand correctly, the code you have explained only sums folders that are in the same directory.

Am I correct ?

Again thank you for your help !

Comment: @titatom You can pass multiple arguments to `du`, e.g. `du dir1 dir2`.

Comment: so I am using this : `du -h dir1 dir2 --max-depth=1 --block-size=GB * | grep "[\/]" | awk '{ val = $1; dir = $2; sub(/^.*\//, "", dir); sizes[dir] += val } \                                                                                                                                                                                                                              END { for (dir in sizes) print dir, sizes[dir], "GB" }' | sort -n -r > ~/lists/disks/test.csv`

It seems the output is only of dir1. and not sum of dir1 and dir2. 

Thank you for your help !

Comment: @titatom Can you edit your question to include the full output of just the `du` command? Without knowing the exact input I can't tell what your issue would be.

Comment: @titatom I ran it with your `du` output and got the expected results (see edit).

Comment: Ok, I'll keep on trying this. Do you think that my grep could be a source of trouble ?

Again thank you for your precious help !

Comment: @titatom I actually ran the exact same commands as you did, except that instead of running du I put the du results from your update in a file and grep'd that.

Comment: Looks like it works ! I ran it without `grep "[\/]"` and it looks fine.

Last question I promise : is it possible to modify this `END { for (dir in sizes) print dir, sizes[dir], "GB" }'` so that size[dir] and GB are written to another column when I `> ~lists/disks/sizes.csv` ?

Cheers !

Comment: @titatom I'm not sure exactly what you mean. You can certainly change the order and format in which things are printed, take a look at some [examples of print](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print-Examples.html#Print-Examples). `awk` also has [printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html#Basic-Printf) for more complex formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the links but I do not find the answer (or don't understand it). When I open the outputted .csv, `dir, sizes[dir], "GB"` is all in column A. I would like to have `dir` in columns A and `sizes[dir], "GB"` in column B

Comment: @titatom Ah I understand now, you're outputting to CSV, didn't catch that. In that case, you need to print commas between fields. Try changing the `print` statement to `print dir","sizes[dir]" GB"`. The double quotes indicate literal strings, so a literal `,` will be printed between the value of `dir` and `sizes[dir]`. More info [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) about quoting in `awk` (actually `gawk` which is the GNU version of `awk`, but I don't think there's anything special in this case about `gawk` vs. `awk`).

Comment: Thank you all my problems are solved ! You've been of great help !

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how many csv files you will need in the end, but maybe this can help:

```
 du -h --block-size=GB ./* | awk -F "[: \t/]" '{size[$NF] += $1} END {for (dir in size) print size[dir], dir}' | sort -n -r
```

The command `size[$NF] += $1` sums over the size (first column) storing the result in the associative array indexed by the directory name (last column).